# How to use HighChart's column-stacked-and-grouped graph dynamic date range in x-axis?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, graph, highcharts

I'm using Highchart's stack and grouped column graph.I want to use a dynamic date-time x-range which can be achieved by passing min and max parameter. I did the same but it's not plotting the graph.
If i remove min and max parameter from x axis and use category array data is populating.but i'm not able to make the category array dynamic,so that i can pass the min and max there and my graph will plot.Need Help.Thanks in Advance.

Below is my dynamicDaterange code.

```
xAxis: {
    type:'datetime',
    min: startDate ?startDate.getTime() : (Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            max: endDate?endDate.getTime() : Date.now(),
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fo3y572b/5/

Below codeline is when i'm using category array

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better approach will be using the **pointStart** and **pointInterval** features.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h2yxbkap/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.pointStart

```
   plotOptions: {
     column: {
       pointStart: startDate,
       pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
       stacking: 'normal'
     }
   },
```

Setting min and max is not enough, it's just set the xAxis range but your data still looks like this `[{x: 0, y: 5}, {x: 1, y: 3}, {x:2, y: 4} , ...]`, which means that x = 0 milliseconds is out of the xAxis range. Or you will need to redefined your data to x as an data.

Comment: Hi Sebastian,Thanks for the update but you are making point interval static but in my case it's dynamic.Let's say user select start date 01/01/2020 and end date as 31/01/2020 then x-axis plot should come as jan,feb,mar and so on. If user select last 5 years data 24/04/2015 to 23/04/2020 then it should come 2015 2016 2017 like this.if user select last 24 hours then it should give me time window also.

Comment: @Aastick so you should defined your data as `[{x: Date.UTC(2018, 9, 18), y: 5}, {x: Date.UTC(2018, 9, 19), y: 7}]` etc. to attach point (defined point position) in the wanted range